# Reassigning union of mutable set

Tags: scala

I have two mutable sets of the same type:

```
val first = mutable.Set(1,2,4)
val second = mutable.Set(2,6,5)
```

I would like to form the union of first and second and reassign the result to first:

```
val first = first union second
```

This does not work, I get the following error message:

```
error: recursive value first needs type
```

How can I re-assign the the union of the two sets to the first set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `first` as a `var`. And then when you update `first`, you don't need to declare it a second time:

```
var first = Set(1,2,4)
val second = Set(5, 2, 6)
first = first union second
```

Values, declared with `val` are immutable. To declare a variable, you use `var`. Then, later when you update the variable, you won't declare it again (you don't need `val` or `var` there), you just refer to it. `val` and `var` are for *creating* values and variables in the first place.

However, I would encourage you to get used to working with immutable values with Scala, and instead prefer something like

```
val first = Set(1,2,4)
val second = Set(5, 2, 6)
val third = first union second
```

this way, you know for sure, at all times, what the value of `first` is. And if you want to work with the union of `first` and `second`, you would use `third`.